# Sporadic Lambda Timeout

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

We have a lambda that has an S3 `ObjectCreated` trigger. When a file is uploaded to a certain S3 bucket and directory in our account, the lambda downloads the file using `boto3` (Python AWS SDK), chunks the content, and PUTs the chunks into many smaller S3 files in a different bucket using `boto3`'s `upload_file` function via parallel processing (strategy for parallel processing in Python Lambda function are outlined [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/)).

The average processing time is around 2 minutes 30 seconds. However the S3 response time was much higher than expected overall, and inevitably one or two lambdas fail due to a Timeout error. The failure rate is very low, and with the timeout setting at 5 minutes, we cannot figure out why we do encounter sporadic Timeout failures when most lambda executions only take 2:30.

We are utilizing the highest memory possible on each lambda, and we have set concurrency at 30 for the lambda in an effort to throttle executions to not exceed S3 PUT object limit.

We do not think this is a code performance issue since most executions fall well within the timeout limit, and we are inclined to think it is AWS-related. We have not been able to determine how we can increase reliable and timely high-volume PUT requests to S3.

Are there additional configuration settings for S3 or Lambda that might help? Or, is there some better way of using `boto3` to reduce overall processing time as well as eliminate the sporadic failures?

Answer (score 0):

The default boto3 retry mode (Legacy) doesn't handle a number of errors/exceptions, including `RequestThrottled`, `PriorRequestNotComplete`, `ConnectionError` and `BandwidthLimitExceeded`. These days, you'll likely be better off using the [Standard retry mode](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/retries.html#standard-retry-mode) instead. The new mode didn't exist at the time of this question, it was [introduced in February 2020](https://github.com/boto/botocore/pull/1972). However, unhandled errors like these could very well have been the cause of this issue at the time.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config as BotoConfig

TIMEOUT = 3
config = BotoConfig(connect_timeout=TIMEOUT, retries={"mode": "standard"})
client = boto3.client("s3", config=config)
```